# MooTools accordion won't collapse nested float in chrome&ie

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, mootools, accordion

While firefox manages, ie and chrome refuse to collapse the div any further than the height of the picture. Additionally (but minor), ie (properly?) wraps the text around the picture, while firefox for some reason i can't figure out has the text seem to float right.

Thanks for any help!

The javascript:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){


 $$( '.bio_accordion' ).each(function(item){

  var thisSlider = new Fx.Slide( item.getElement( '.moreInfo' ), { mode: 'horizontal' } );
  thisSlider.hide();


item.getElement('.moreInfo').set('tween').tween('height', '0px');

  var morph = new Fx.Morph(item.getElement( '.divToggle' ));
  var selected = 0;
  item.getElement( '.divToggle' ).addEvents({
  'mouseenter': function(){
   if(!selected) this.morph('.div_highlight');
  },

  'mouseleave': function(){
   if(!selected) {
    this.morph('.divToggle');
   }
  },

  'click': function(){
   if (!selected){
    if (this.getElement('.symbol').innerHTML == '+')
    this.getElement('.symbol').innerHTML = '-';
    else
    this.getElement('.symbol').innerHTML = '+';
    thisSlider.slideIn();
    item.getElement('.moreInfo').set('tween', {
     duration: 1500,
     transition: Fx.Transitions.Bounce.easeOut
    }).tween('height', '650px');
    selected = 1;
   }
   else{
    if (this.getElement('.symbol').innerHTML == '+')
    this.getElement('.symbol').innerHTML = '-';
    else
    this.getElement('.symbol').innerHTML = '+';
    thisSlider.slideOut();
    item.getElement('.moreInfo').set('tween', {
     duration: 1500,
     transition: Fx.Transitions.Bounce.easeOut
    }).tween('height', '0px');
    selected = 0;
   }
  }
  });

 } );




});
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="bio_accordion">

<div class="divToggle">Lorem Ipsum<span class="symbol">-</span></div>
<div class="moreInfo" style="margin-left:10px;">

<div class="photo"><img src="http://loremipsum.com/images/3.jpg" /></div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

The css:

```
.bio_accordion
{
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
}

.divToggle
{
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #ffffff;
 background-color:#1089b5;
 padding: 8px;
}

.div_highlight
{
 padding-left:30px;
 padding-right:30px;
 background-color:#096687;
}

.moreInfo
{
 padding: 2px;
}

.symbol
{
 float:right;
}

.photo
{
 float:left;
 padding-right:10px;
 height:inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
.moreInfo
{
 padding: 2px;
}
```

to

```
.moreInfo
{
   padding: 2px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```